# facebook invite friend - Track referrer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am planning to create a facebook app where a user invites his/her facebook friends using fb API and when that friend/s responds to the invitation and lands on the app, i want to track who of my fb friend referred me to this app. In short, I wanted to ask if is it possible on facebook that we can track the user who invites friend/s to an app?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was to keep track of which friends a user invites using the [Multi-friend selector](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/custom-multi-friend-selector/)

Prevent other users from inviting the same friend for 7 days.

If the friend signs up, attribute it to the last user that sent him/her an invite.

The problem with this is that it is not 100% accurate. I too am looking for a better solution.